# Enable/disable analytics for tracking push notifications after MarketingCloud SDK initialization? (iOS)

Tags: mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, analytics, mobilepush-ios

MarketingCloud analytics for tracking push notifcations can be enabled by calling `setAnalyticsEnabled(true)` on the `PushConfigBuilder` instance when initializing SFMCSdk, as explained [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configuresdk.html).

We would like to enable/disable analytics according to user consent for tracking, to make our app 100% GDPR compliant.

In our app user can update user consent multiple times, so is there a way to enable/disable MC analytics without reinitialising SDK?

Comment: We're working on adding runtime feature toggles in our next release. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the new [Mobile Push SDK (8.1.0) and SFMCSDK (1.1.0)](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/#version-810)! You can now use the [Runtime Toggles API](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/runtime-toggles.html) to enable/disabled features like Analytics, Location, and Inbox Messages.

```swift
SFMCSdk.requestPushSdk { mp in
    mp.setAnalyticsEnabled(false)
    
    let _ = mp.isAnalyticsEnabled()
}
```